# Жизненный цикл Activity и его фрагментов

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

У меня в  активити есть класс TabAdapter, который, на одну из вкладок (с индексом 0) выводит фрагмент, GroupList. Сам TabAdapter создается в onCreate, активити. По кнопке список заполняется данными. Всё работает, всё ок, пока не перевернешь телефон. При перевороте отрабатывает тот же onCreate, но что-то идет не так. У фрагмента, который пытается заполниться по кнопке, адаптер списка оказывается null. В целях отладки я вывел в логи, информацию о создании GroupList и срабатывании его жизненного цикла (адаптер инициализируется в onCreate фрагмента). Что получилось видно на скрине (обратите внимание на id объектов). В синей рамке часть лога, после переворота экрана.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать методы `onSaveInstanceState` и `onRestoreInstanceState` для сохранения данных при повороте экрана и восстановления их после поворота.
Либо можете попробовать просто сохранить фрагмент в памяти (с помощью `setRetainInstance(true)`), и снова использовать его после поворота экрана.

Объяснение (ответ на вопрос "Кто создал этот фрагмент?") в том, что при восстановлении активности после поворота она будет автоматически восстанавливать фрагменты, которые были добавлены в него, так что добавление нового фрагмента в вашей активности будет добавлять еще один новый фрагмент поверх предыдущего фрагмента(или фрагментов), которые уже были восстановлены.

Именно поэтому у вас в логах и появляется после поворота экрана два раза запись

> GroupList GroupList()

**UPD**

Для того, чтобы добраться до фрагмента в конструкторе `TabAdapter'а`, вы можете использовать теги. Например, при создании фрагмента добавьте тег:

```
groupList = new GroupList();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.your_placeholder, groupList, "YOUR_TAG")
    .commit();
```

где `your_placeholder` - id виджета, на месте которого должен отображаться фрагмент.
А далее доступ к фрагменту можно получить через метод `findFragmentByTag()`.

Comment: Дело в том, что в данном конкретном случае меня вполне устроило бы все создать заново, чего я и пытался добиться.

Comment: выложите, пожалуйста, свой код

Comment: https://github.com/WaterSmith/testRotateScreen

Comment: а где у вас идёт вывод лога "return GroupList"?

Comment: Пока примеры готовил, случайно затер. Этот вывод должен быть в TabAdapter, в методе getItem: Log.i(TAG,"return "+groupList); Уже исправил

Comment: @СергейВодаков, я обновила ответ

Comment: Да, действительно, FragmentManager восстановился, и в нем есть нужный мне фрагмент. Но, остается открытым вопрос, как мне его извлечь в конструкторе TabAdapter? Вот что я вижу в отладчике: http://prnt.sc/chegsx

Comment: Вы наверное посоветуете мне использовать  findFragmentById() но, по id прописанному в макете фрагмента он не находится. В отладчике можно увидеть что у него другой id. Я вычислил что это id ViewPager, в котором выводятся закладки. Но, если закладок будет больше одной, то у всех фрагментов будет одинаковый id (я проверил). Что же делать?

Comment: @СергейВодаков, а где находится это id, "прописанному в макете фрагмента"? В макетах вашего проекта я вообще не нашла фрагментов, по-моему, они у вас только программно создаются...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45303/discussion-between---and-ksenia).